# Jquery trigger or click an anchor

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me why this code is not working.
I'm trying to click on an anchor when a user sets a date on my jquery datepicker.
Would appreciate any help.

```
<a class="bye"  id="bye" href="google.com" >Go To Google</a>
```

```
$( "#to" ).datepicker(
{
  onSelect: function()
  {
    $('#bye').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it inside the `$(document).ready()` handler?

Comment: nope. do I need to declare that? Because if i replace the click event with a alert it works.

Comment: If the datepicker is showing, then you don't need to.

Comment: `window.location = $('#bye').prop('href')` -- instead of `$('#bye').click()`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for that but it feels I bypassed the anchor. Because I'm gonna move to another different scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click()` fires any javascript click handlers attached to the element.  This does not trigger the default action of an anchor tag so it will not take you to the page.

You could do something like this:

```
window.location = $('#bye').attr('href');
```

Comment: I have numerous spans that are database generated. On those spans are jqueries that handle clicks on span. So from what you said `click()` would also fire those events am I right?

Comment: `click()` would fire those.

Comment: I just used this for a test but not is not working. `$('#bye').click();` for this element `<a class="bye"  id="bye" onClick="alert('Hello World!')" href="#" >Go To Google</a>`

Comment: That should work just fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/Xm6t6/  Ensure that your code is inside `$(document).ready` or at some time when the element exists.

Comment: the `$('#bye').click();` is inside the onSelect function above this post. and its inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: Perhaps you can create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the issue, because that should work.

Answer (score 0):

.click() is a javascript event so you must catch this event in javascript. Try add on your javascript code look like below:

```
$('#bye').click(function(){
    //window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LDG4n/3/